# Как сделать выборку по нескольким параметрам в MongoDB(Mongoose)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Мне нужно сделать роут по которому можно будет по разным параметрам сортировать продукты в интернет-магазине.Я себе представляю это так, post запросом отправляется массив с параметрами по которым нужно отсортировать на сервере этот массив обрабатывается и ищет только по тем параметрам которые были указаны в массиве.

Но у меня возникает вопрос "Как сказать монго что если есть в массиве параметр то ищи по нему, а ели нету то не нужно" так как в массиве будут строки.

Вот то что сам смог написать:

```
router.post('/sort',(req,res,next) => {
    const sort = req.params.sortBy; // массив который был в body
    Product.find({ gender : req.body.gender}) //обьект сортировки mongoose
    .then(response => {
        res.status(200).json(response)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: перед передачей параметров объектом нужно точно отфильтровать undefined значения, а также возможно null или `""` - смотря по обстоятельствам

Comment: также потребуется задать индексы